# React многоуровневый массив

Tags: reactjs, redux

Добрый день, есть массив:

```
[
    {
        "id": "596e1e157919a897e4800a3b",
        "name": "Chair L",
        "description": "Light plastic chair",
        "imageUrls": [
            "/api/image/img2.jpg"
        ],
        "materials": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a17",
                "name": "Wood",
                "description": "The best material, but very expensive material."
            }
        ],
        "colors": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a25",
                "name": "Red",
                "hexCode": "#FF0000"
            }
        ],
        "volume": {
            "volume": "MEDIUM"
        },
        "type": "MODEL3D",
        "brand": {
            "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a12",
            "name": "Palecek",
            "description": "Alan Palacek created this brand 40 years ago."
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a23",
                "name": "sleeping",
                "description": "all staff for sleeping",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1c",
                        "name": "sofa"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1d",
                        "name": "bed"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1e",
                        "name": "hammock"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a24",
                "name": "storage",
                "description": "all staff for storage",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1f",
                        "name": "cupboard"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a20",
                        "name": "nightstand"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a21",
                        "name": "basket"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "rooms": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a34",
                "name": "Bedroom",
                "description": "All staff for bedroom"
            }
        ],
        "urlToShopOrDraw": null,
        "price": {
            "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a2a",
            "amount": 299,
            "currency": "Dollars"
        },
        "info": {
            "Brand": [
                "Palecek"
            ],
            "Category": [
                "sleeping",
                "storage"
            ],
            "Color": [
                "#FF0000"
            ],
            "Room": [
                "Bedroom"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "596e1e157919a897e4800a3d",
        "name": "The best Sofa",
        "description": "Biggest and cheapest then other sofas",
        "imageUrls": [
            "/api/image/img4.jpg"
        ],
        "materials": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a16",
                "name": "Metal",
                "description": "Strong material."
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a17",
                "name": "Wood",
                "description": "The best material, but very expensive material."
            }
        ],
        "colors": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a26",
                "name": "Blue",
                "hexCode": "#3914AF"
            }
        ],
        "volume": {
            "volume": "SMALL"
        },
        "type": "MODEL3D",
        "brand": {
            "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a14",
            "name": "BOYD",
            "description": "Another American brand which create furniture."
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a22",
                "name": "seats",
                "description": "all staff for sitting",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a19",
                        "name": "chair"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1a",
                        "name": "pouf"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1b",
                        "name": "bench"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a23",
                "name": "sleeping",
                "description": "all staff for sleeping",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1c",
                        "name": "sofa"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1d",
                        "name": "bed"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1e",
                        "name": "hammock"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a24",
                "name": "storage",
                "description": "all staff for storage",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1f",
                        "name": "cupboard"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a20",
                        "name": "nightstand"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a21",
                        "name": "basket"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "rooms": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a33",
                "name": "Kitchen",
                "description": "All staff for kitchen"
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a34",
                "name": "Bedroom",
                "description": "All staff for bedroom"
            }
        ],
        "urlToShopOrDraw": null,
        "price": {
            "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a2c",
            "amount": 499,
            "currency": "Dollars"
        },
        "info": {
            "Brand": [
                "BOYD"
            ],
            "Category": [
                "seats",
                "sleeping",
                "storage"
            ],
            "Color": [
                "#3914AF"
            ],
            "Room": [
                "Kitchen",
                "Bedroom"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "596e1e157919a897e4800a3f",
        "name": "Table S",
        "description": "Strong metal Table! For real man !",
        "imageUrls": [
            "/api/image/img6.jpg"
        ],
        "materials": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a16",
                "name": "Metal",
                "description": "Strong material."
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a17",
                "name": "Wood",
                "description": "The best material, but very expensive material."
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a18",
                "name": "Plastic",
                "description": "Very popular material."
            }
        ],
        "colors": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a27",
                "name": "Green",
                "hexCode": "#00CB00"
            }
        ],
        "volume": {
            "volume": "LARGE"
        },
        "type": "MODEL3D",
        "brand": {
            "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a11",
            "name": "Rowe",
            "description": "American furniture brand. Started in 1970. Very big fabric."
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a22",
                "name": "seats",
                "description": "all staff for sitting",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a19",
                        "name": "chair"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1a",
                        "name": "pouf"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1b",
                        "name": "bench"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a23",
                "name": "sleeping",
                "description": "all staff for sleeping",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1c",
                        "name": "sofa"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1d",
                        "name": "bed"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1e",
                        "name": "hammock"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "rooms": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a33",
                "name": "Kitchen",
                "description": "All staff for kitchen"
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a34",
                "name": "Bedroom",
                "description": "All staff for bedroom"
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a35",
                "name": "Restroom",
                "description": "All staff for restroom"
            }
        ],
        "urlToShopOrDraw": null,
        "price": {
            "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a2e",
            "amount": 699,
            "currency": "Dollars"
        },
        "info": {
            "Brand": [
                "Rowe"
            ],
            "Category": [
                "seats",
                "sleeping"
            ],
            "Color": [
                "#00CB00"
            ],
            "Room": [
                "Kitchen",
                "Bedroom",
                "Restroom"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "596e1e157919a897e4800a41",
        "name": "Table M",
        "description": "Medium metal/plastic table for kitchen",
        "imageUrls": [
            "/api/image/img8.jpg"
        ],
        "materials": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a17",
                "name": "Wood",
                "description": "The best material, but very expensive material."
            }
        ],
        "colors": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a25",
                "name": "Red",
                "hexCode": "#FF0000"
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a26",
                "name": "Blue",
                "hexCode": "#3914AF"
            }
        ],
        "volume": {
            "volume": "MEDIUM"
        },
        "type": "MODEL3D",
        "brand": {
            "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a13",
            "name": "Maison 55",
            "description": " American furniture brand"
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a23",
                "name": "sleeping",
                "description": "all staff for sleeping",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1c",
                        "name": "sofa"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1d",
                        "name": "bed"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1e",
                        "name": "hammock"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "rooms": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a33",
                "name": "Kitchen",
                "description": "All staff for kitchen"
            }
        ],
        "urlToShopOrDraw": null,
        "price": {
            "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a30",
            "amount": 899,
            "currency": "Dollars"
        },
        "info": {
            "Brand": [
                "Maison 55"
            ],
            "Category": [
                "sleeping"
            ],
            "Color": [
                "#FF0000",
                "#3914AF"
            ],
            "Room": [
                "Kitchen"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "596e1e157919a897e4800a43",
        "name": "Sofa-Table",
        "description": "Big sofa with table which integrated in this sofa",
        "imageUrls": [
            "/api/image/img10.jpg"
        ],
        "materials": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a16",
                "name": "Metal",
                "description": "Strong material."
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a17",
                "name": "Wood",
                "description": "The best material, but very expensive material."
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a18",
                "name": "Plastic",
                "description": "Very popular material."
            }
        ],
        "colors": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a25",
                "name": "Red",
                "hexCode": "#FF0000"
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a26",
                "name": "Blue",
                "hexCode": "#3914AF"
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a27",
                "name": "Green",
                "hexCode": "#00CB00"
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a28",
                "name": "Black",
                "hexCode": "#000000"
            }
        ],
        "volume": {
            "volume": "SMALL"
        },
        "type": "MODEL3D",
        "brand": {
            "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a15",
            "name": "Sterling",
            "description": "Big and famous American brand!"
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a22",
                "name": "seats",
                "description": "all staff for sitting",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a19",
                        "name": "chair"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1a",
                        "name": "pouf"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1b",
                        "name": "bench"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a23",
                "name": "sleeping",
                "description": "all staff for sleeping",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1c",
                        "name": "sofa"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1d",
                        "name": "bed"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1e",
                        "name": "hammock"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a24",
                "name": "storage",
                "description": "all staff for storage",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a1f",
                        "name": "cupboard"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a20",
                        "name": "nightstand"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a21",
                        "name": "basket"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "rooms": [
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a33",
                "name": "Kitchen",
                "description": "All staff for kitchen"
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a34",
                "name": "Bedroom",
                "description": "All staff for bedroom"
            },
            {
                "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a35",
                "name": "Restroom",
                "description": "All staff for restroom"
            }
        ],
        "urlToShopOrDraw": null,
        "price": {
            "id": "596e1e147919a897e4800a32",
            "amount": 1099,
            "currency": "Dollars"
        },
        "info": {
            "Brand": [
                "Sterling"
            ],
            "Category": [
                "seats",
                "sleeping",
                "storage"
            ],
            "Color": [
                "#FF0000",
                "#3914AF",
                "#00CB00",
                "#000000"
            ],
            "Room": [
                "Kitchen",
                "Bedroom",
                "Restroom"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

С него мне нужно получить `info` и все его данные (делаю так, получаю):

```
                        {Object.keys(item.info).map((key) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="back-info">
                                    <p className='grey-text text-lighten-1'>{key}</p>
                                    <div className="info-data">
                                        <a className='grey-text text-darken-4'>{item.info[key]}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
```

Далее хочу сделать так, чтобы данные с массива `info` -> `color` записывались в тег `a` и находилось в моем `Object.keys` примерно так, но как именно это сделать не знаю:

```
<a className='color-box' style={{background: тут value с color}}></a>
```

Выглядит оно сейчас так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но вместо Hex кода хочу, чтобы отображался цвет.

Подскажите, как правильно переписать код, чтобы получить отдельно цвет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свою проблему решил вот так:

```
                    <div className="info-wrap">
                        {Object.keys(item.info).map((key, ind) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={ind} className="back-info">
                                    <p className='grey-text text-lighten-1'>{key}</p>
                                    <div className="info-data">
                                        {item.info[key].map((value) => {
                                            {if (key === 'Color') {
                                                return (<a className='color-box' style={{background: value}}></a>)
                                            } else {
                                                return (<a className='grey-text text-darken-4'>{value}</a>)
                                            }
                                        }})}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
```